# Python - Updating Label Text Within Window Class from outside Function

Tags: python, tkinter

Good Afternoon All,

I am trying to write an app that runs my HVAC, and a number of other systems, running on a raspberry PI.  I will be the first to admit that python and I are not good friends.  However, the driver library for the sensors I am using do not seem to be compatible with Java or anything else I am better prepared to code in.   I have spent a few days search for the answer on this but have failed to find one that has worked for me.

Essentially I am trying to get the getcurrentTH() function to update the currenttempLabel in the GUI.  I keep getting a error.

Name Error: name currenttempLabel is not defined

I am guessing it has something to do with how I am trying to call the label inside the class from a function outside.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Code is below.

```
import mysql.connector
import time
import Adafruit_DHT as dht
from tkinter import *
import random
import _thread
import threading

started = 0
currentTemp = 0
currentHumidity = 0

def getcurrentTH():
    while started > 0:
        global currentTemp
        global currentHumidity
        h,t = dht.read_retry(dht.DHT22, 4)
        currentTemp = ((t *1.8) + 32)
        currentHumidity = h
        currenttempLabel['text'] = currentTemp
        time.sleep(5)

def start():
    global started
    started = 1
    print("started")
    print(started)
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=getcurrentTH)
    t3.start()


def stop():
    global started
    started = 0

def quitapp():
    exit()

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master

        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        global currentTemp
        global currentHumidty

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        startButton = Button(self, height = 3, width = 5, bg = "light green", text= "Start", command=start)

        startButton.place(x=625, y=50)

        stopButton = Button(self, height =3, width =5, bg = "red",  text = "Stop", command=stop)

        stopButton.place(x=625, y=150)

        statusLabel = Label(self,  text = "Current Status: N/A")

        statusLabel.place(x=600, y=125)

        quitButton = Button(self, height =3, width = 5, text = "Quit", command=quitapp)

        quitButton.place(x=625, y=500)

        currenttempLabel = Label(self, font = ("Courier",26), text = "No Current Reading" )
        currenttempLabel.place(x=50, y=50)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `currenttempLabel` is a local variable within `Window.init_window`. As soon as that function exits, the variable goes away, and there's no way to access its value anymore.

If you want to store those widgets in variables that can be accessed later, the simplest thing to do is to put them in attributes of the object:

```
self.currenttempLabel = Label(self, font = ("Courier",26), text = "No Current Reading" )
self.currenttempLabel.place(x=50, y=50)
```

Now, you can access them through the global `app` variable. (It might be better to pass the `Window` object around, or move those top-level functions into `Window` methods that can access it as `self`, instead of storing it as a global. But since you already have a global in your current design, you can just use that.)

```
app.currenttempLabel['text'] = currentTemp
```

---

However, once you fix that, you have another major problem:

```
t3 = threading.Thread(target=getcurrentTH)
```

Code that's not running in the main thread isn't allowed to touch any tkinter widgets. Depending on your platform, it may raise an exception, hang the GUI, crash, or, worst of all, work about 90% of the time but occasionally do something wrong.

There are a number of ways to work around this problem. The main one is described in [this article in the Tkinter book](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm): create a `queue.Queue`, make the main thread poll `q.get_nowait()` and call any functions it finds there, and have the background thread just `q.put` functions instead of calling them directly.

There's a library named [`mttkinter`](https://pypi.org/project/mttkinter/) that wraps up this technique, but it was for Python 2.3; the port to Python 2.7 looks pretty solid, but for 3.x, I only know of mostly-untested and unmaintained forks like [the one I slapped together a few years ago because none of the others worked](https://github.com/abarnert/mttkinter). So, if you want to go this way, you'll still have to understand how things are working under the covers, so you can test and maintain it yourself.

Comment: abarnet for some reason I was reading your response on my phone and the entire second section on threading was not visible.  I appreciate the information it is my first time working with threading in python.

Rather then creating a queue would it also be possible to use the function to to update the global variable and then use another function within window function that does nothing but periodically update the label using the after() mechanism ?